# JS - Loop over array of object and output the property

Tags: javascript

How can I loop over this array of objects and output the *key* of the object

```
var people = [
  { name: "jon", age: 42 },
  { name: "mary", age: 32 }
]
```

so the above would return:

// "name" "age", "name" "age"

Comment: `people.forEach( x => console.log(Object.keys(x)))`

Comment: thanks Satpal. But I see your method actually converts the properties on the object into array items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the array and use the for ... in loop to output the keys.

```js
var people = [
  { name: "jon", age: 42 },
  { name: "mary", age: 32 }
]

people.forEach(function(element) {
  for (let key in element) {
    console.log(key);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys()` to extract keys from an object.

```js
var people = [
  { name: "jon", age: 42 },
  { name: "mary", age: 32 }
]

console.log(people.map(o => Object.keys(o).join(" ")).join(", "));
```

Another example to match the exact output:

```js
var people = [{
  name: "jon",
  age: 42
}, {
  name: "mary",
  age: 32
}]

var result = people.map(o => Object.keys(o).map(string => `"${string}"`).join(' ')).join(', ');
console.log(result);
```